# Outer Join using multiple Google Sheets and the QUERY function

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

As an example, say I have the following sheets in the same workbook of a Google Doc:

```
 SHEET1            |   SHEET2
 \   A  |  B       |   \   A   |   B   |   C   |   D
1|  ID  |Lookup    |  1| Lookup| Name  |Flavor | Color
2|  123 | 4445     |  2| 1234  |Whizzer|Cherry | Red
3|  234 | 4445     |  3| 4445  |Fizzer |Lemon  | Yellow
4|  124 | 1234     |  4| 9887  |Sizzle |Lime   | Blue
5|  767 | 1234     |
6|  555 | 9887     |
```

Obviously, Google Docs isn't made with relational databases in mind, but I am trying to obtain results similar to the SQL query

```
SELECT
  SHEET1.ID,
  SHEET2.*
FROM 
  SHEET1 
    LEFT JOIN
      SHEET2
    ON SHEET1.Lookup = SHEET2.Lookup
```

resulting in a table that looks like

```
 SHEET3            
 \   A    |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   
1|   ID   |Lookup | Name  |Flavor | Color
2|  123   | 4445  |Fizzer |Lemon  | Yellow
3|  234   | 4445  |Fizzer |Lemon  | Yellow
4|  124   | 1234  |Whizzer|Cherry | Red
5|  767   | 1234  |Whizzer|Cherry | Red
6|  555   | 9887  |Sizzle |Lime   | Blue
```

but this is where I stand currently

```
 SHEET3            
 \   A    |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   
1|        |       |       |       |
2|  123   | 4445  | #N/A  |       |
3|  234   | 4445  |       |       |
4|  124   | 1234  |       |       |
5|  767   | 1234  |       |       |
6|  555   | 9887  |       |       |
```

At the moment I have managed to use the `QUERY` function to grab the values from `SHEET1` and have tried a few different `QUERY` functions in `SHEET3!C1` in an attempt to "`LEFT JOIN`" the two sheets using [this blog post](http://the-byting-experience.blogspot.com/2011/10/google-spreadsheet-as-database.html) as a reference. At this point, the two functions I am using are as follows.

`SHEET3!A2=QUERY(SHEET1!A2:B20, "SELECT A,B")`
`SHEET3!C2=QUERY(SHEET2!A2:E20, "SELECT B,C,D WHERE A="""&B2&"""")`

and hovering over the error in `C2` reads "Query completed with an empty output". How can I join these sheets?

Additional references:
[Google Docs syntax page for QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: Added desired results. I assumed that the SQL code I was trying to emulate was enough, but it's not possible to be too thorough.

Answer (score 6):

Do this in Sheet3.

In cell A1, to get the correct headings:

```
={Sheet1!A1:B1,Sheet2!B1:D1}
```

In cell A2, to get the table of Joined data, try this formula:

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!A2:B,
 VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B2:B, {Sheet2!A2:A, Sheet2!B2:D}, {2,3,4}, false)},
 Sheet1!B2:B<>"")
```

I've written a comprehensive guide about this topic called:

#### ['Mastering Join-formulas in Google Sheets'](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14fVgEfdxsiBZGAqEP9qpySM1W28HEFzFYcXd6daNH38/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Viktor, this is great, thank you! This solved my problem. I have one question though, I've implemented your solution for my sheet, but one of my rows is showing #NA with the error "Did not find value '224517' in VLOOKUP evaluation.". How would I prevent the display of this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy SHEET1 into SHEET3 (A1) then in C2:

```
=vlookup($B2,Sheet2!$A:$D,column()-1,0)
```

copied across and down should give the results you show once you have added three column labels.

Comment: Mate, you can get a table of joined data with only one formula (in one cell), given that you combine Vlookup with Arrayformula or the Filter-function and curly brackets. No need to copy across and down.

Answer (score 0):

The following Add-on will provide all you need: **[Formulas by Top Contributors](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/formulas_by_top_contributors/515924842729)**, by using both the build-in SQL join types and the MATRIX formula:

```
=MATRIX(SQLINNERJOIN(Sheet1!A1:B6,2,Sheet2!A1:D4,1, TRUE),,"3")
```

It will yield the following outcome:
[image]

I've created an example file for you: **[SQL JOINS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16P-FVPw846zcRqwQ-WWvjumEvuEqIKixTHmXaZIF9Nw/edit?usp=sharing)**

<sup>Affiliation: as a Google Top Contributor I helped creating the Add-on</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Sheet3!A2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A2:B20)
```

Sheet3!C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B20,A1:D50,{2,3,4},0))
```

Comment: Try encapsulating the Vlookup-function with another pair of curly brackets and it might work better...