# How to JOIN tables with duplicated keys and produce multiple entries?

Tags: pandas, google-sheets, join, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 tables in different Google worksheets:

`Sheet1`:

```
Key ValueOne    ValueTwo
1   3001            R
1   3002            R
1   3003            C
2   3001            P
2   3004            P
2   3005            P
3   3002            C
3   3006            C
```

`Sheet2`:

```
Key ValueThree  ValueFour
1   ABC         25
1   CDE         25
2   ABC         27
2   CDE         29
2   GFH         40
3   BCD         45
```

I want to get as a result table like this:
`Sheet3`:

```
Key ValueOne    ValueTwo    ValueThree  ValueFour
1   3001            R           ABC         25
1   3001            R           CDE         25
1   3002            R           ABC         25
1   3002            R           CDE         25
1   3003            C           ABC         25
1   3003            C           CDE         25
2   3001            P           ABC         27
2   3001            P           CDE         29
2   3001            P           GFH         40
2   3004            P           ABC         27
2   3004            P           CDE         29
2   3004            P           GFH         40
```

The logic is kinda that each entries from both tables are producing m * n duplicated entries in a new table. This is what Python Pandas `merge()` does and I want to replicate that in Google Sheets.

The closest available solution that I found is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361243/outer-join-using-multiple-google-sheets-and-the-query-function) and [guide](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14fVgEfdxsiBZGAqEP9qpySM1W28HEFzFYcXd6daNH38/edit?usp=sharing), which works using this formula:

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!A2:B,
 VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B2:B, {Sheet2!A2:A, Sheet2!B2:D}, {2,3,4}, false)},
 Sheet1!B2:B<>"")
```

but the issue, that the second table there has a unique keys, and mine - is not.

Comment: how did you calculate ValueFour in the new table?

Comment: try merge on key

Comment: @ztiaa oh sorry, it should just be duplicated from Sheet2. In the end, I decided to replace ones and twos with bigger values - to not make it look similar to the key

Answer (score 0):

<s>It's not clear to me how you calculated `ValueFour` in the new table</s>

You can try something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( 
   LET(_CROSSJOIN,LAMBDA(range,SPLIT(REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(range)),LAMBDA(a,i,TOCOL(a&"ζ"&TOROW(INDEX(range,,i),1)))),"ζ",,)),
   CHOOSECOLS(
     REDUCE({0,Sheet1!A1:C1,Sheet2!B1:C1},
            TOCOL(UNIQUE({Sheet1!A2:A;Sheet2!A2:A}),1),
            LAMBDA(new_table,key,
              VSTACK(
                new_table,
               _CROSSJOIN(
                  IFNA(HSTACK(
                         key,
                         BYROW(IFNA(FILTER(Sheet1!B2:C,Sheet1!A2:A=key),HSTACK(,)),LAMBDA(r,JOIN("ζ",r))),
                         BYROW(IFNA(FILTER(Sheet2!B2:C,Sheet2!A2:A=key),HSTACK(,)),LAMBDA(r,JOIN("ζ",r))))))))),
     2,3,4,5,6)))
```

This formula assumes that the first table is in `Sheet1!A:C` and the second table is in `Sheet2!A:C`.

The way it works is by essentially performing a cross join between the corresponding values of each key and then stacking the results together.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try (`for setup as in screenshot`):*

```js
=let(Σ,filter(A2:C,A2:A<>""),
 reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(rows(Σ)),lambda(a,c,ifna(let(Λ,ifna(filter(F:G,E:E=index(index(Σ,,1),c))),vstack(a,hstack(chooserows(index(Σ,c),sequence(rows(Λ),1,1,0)),Λ)))))))
```

[image]

***Scenario 2*** (`if some keys are present ONLY in Sheet1 OR Sheet2; refer screenshot`)

```js
=let(Σ,vstack(filter(A2:C,A2:A<>""),unique(ifna(filter(E2:E,isna(xmatch(E2:E,A2:A)),E2:E<>"")))),
     reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(rows(Σ)),lambda(a,c,ifna(let(Λ,ifna(filter(F:G,E:E=index(index(Σ,,1),c))),vstack(a,hstack(chooserows(index(Σ,c),sequence(rows(Λ),1,1,0)),Λ)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Also can you clarify on whats the expected scenario like if lets say Key value `3` is present ONLY in *Sheet1* (not present in *Sheet2*) OR vice-versa(present ONLY in *Sheet2*)?!